ignore visual level filter, but keep page level filter
TL;DR: a measure is reused by some table visuals, how to ignore the visuals filters (i.e. the columns in the table visuals) and keep only the page level filter?

Hi,
I have this measure used by a few table visuals, I don't want the table columns further filter it, only page level filter needed. I.e. Table A has column Issuer_Name and table B has column IL_SP_2017_Industry, so I excluded them in the RemoveFilters
collateral principal amount ALL issuer = 
    var prinBalance_xEquity_xDefault = 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(PrincipalActivity[PRINBALANCE]), 
            PrincipalActivity[Asset_AssetType_Name] <> "Equity", 
            PrincipalActivity[IsDefaulted] = FALSE(),

             // manually exclude table columns
            REMOVEFILTERS(PrincipalActivity[Issuer_Name], PrincipalActivity[IL_SP_2017_Industry])

        )
    var tradeDateCash = SUM('compliance PortfolioLevel'[TradeDateCash_IND])
RETURN 
    prinBalance_xEquity_xDefault + tradeDateCash

But this is repetitive. If I use it in another table, then will need to manually add new columns to RemoveFilters. How can I have it ignore visual level filter? I've tried replacing RemoveFilters ALLSELECTED(PrincipalActivity) but it gave weird numbers
Thank you!

ALLSELECTED could be an option, explain more on the "weird numbers". Hard to answer your question without understanding your data model and which page level filters you are wanting to keep. It sounds like you will need to separate the relevant data from the tables with the dimensions you want to ignore/exclude.
